# Exception of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Contracts.GitCheckoutConflictException' was thrown

Tags: git, visual-studio

While trying to checkout to a new branch in Visual Studio 2019, I'm getting the below error:
[image]

I tried to do the same from `GitBash cmd` using the command `git checkout branchname` but here also, I'm getting an error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
//list of file names below
...
...
...
Aborting
```

I tried restarting VS also but it was of no help. Can you please assist?

Comment: The Git command line error message *also* tells you how to *fix* the problem using the Git command line. (I have no idea what to do with VS, but if you want a Git command line answer, this is a duplicate.)

Comment: I get this same error now. I upgraded from VS 2019 to VS 2022 recently and seem to get this after that change. The exact exception is:
Exception of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Contracts.GitRemoteRefNotFoundException' was thrown

Would love to see a fix.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this same error and solved it the following way, note I am calling my branch as myBranchName...
Within visual studio in the git-manage branches screen, it just shows that error over and over. But, I navigated to the folder in windows, right-mouse context menu and chose 'git bash here' to open bash (which you can install along with GIT for windows in the same installer), in that folder. Then I typed

```html
git checkout -b myBranchName
```

and pressed enter. This worked with no error.
Then I returned to visual studio and it showed myBranchName in the bottom right of the screen.

Note: Also this all assumes your "new branch name" is an existing branch, in my case it was an existing branch that existed already remotely and locally when I got that error. If this is different from your question, then this may/may not help.

Comment: In my case, VS2022 prompted with the error mentioned in the title (even after restarting VS2022) with no further info (not even in the 'Source Control - Git' output window). I then Opened a Command Prompt and navigated to the git folder for my solution, and ran `git checkout myBranchName` (where myBranchname was the branch in question) and it provided **more information...** it informed me that a file would be overidden (or something). I made a backup and deleted the particular file... and re-attempted from VS. and it all worked out, no errors. git command line provided me with the info needed

Comment: Using the bash-command worked for me as well by providing more information: In my case I had set a config-file to --assume-unchanged which would have been overwritten by the remote.

Answer (score 4):

On my side the issue was a difference of .gitignore content between the source branch and the destination branch.
Indeed the destination branch had more exclusions defined in .gitignore than in source branch (ex: *.suo).
This hint came from the fact that I commited and push just before the .suo file on source branch, what I was not doing from a long time in destination branch.

So here is the fix I applied:

- get the .gitignore from destination branch
- use it to replace the one in source branch,
- commit and push source branch,
- close the solution,
- open the solution.

Then it was possible to switch to destination branch without error.

Comment: This worked for me even though I only did the first two steps. There was one exclusion defined in the source branch that was not in the dest branch, then I just replaced the source branch with the version from the destination branch. After that VS allowed me to checkout the branch (and I chose the option to bring the changes to the destination branch).
After the checkout, there weren't any changes in git.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue and the below steps worked for me

1. Navigated to `\.git\refs\remotes` folder in my local system
2. Deleted the branch that was causing the issue
3. Now i checked out the branch using git bash using `git checkout <branchname>`

Comment: I didn't have to do step 1 but steps 2 & 3 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I fixed this:

Our Cause:
We reset our repository's master branch, but the master branch only had the initial git file.  The rest of our work was delegated to a backup branch that we were going to merge via a pull request.  After resetting master and moving the data to the new branch, whenever we tried to pull the data from the remote/origin into visual studio from the backup branch, it caused this exception.  We tried removing the solution and redownloading, and other techniques, but each one failed.

First Solution:
After many attempts, I recreated a .vs solution in Master and pasted the .gitignore, Jenkins, and Nuget files from the backup.  For some reason after that local commit, I was able to pull the backup commit without the exception.

Second Solution:
Deciding that maybe it had something to do with either the .gitignore,Jenkins,Nuget files being out of sync, I decided to try again.  I deleted the repository from my computer, again, and pulled the repository, again.  I copied and pasted the .gitignore, Jenkins, and Nuget files into the master branch, and locally committed.  Following that, I was once again able to pull the Backup branch without visual studio throwing the exception.  So, for us, it had something to do with either one of those files, or for some reason we just needed to make a local commit on Master before it would allow us to pull any additional branches.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the .suo file.
See link below for description.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-user-options-dot-suo-file?view=vs-2022

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30795669)

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers helped me. In the end I simply re-cloned the repo to a different folder and it started working again.

If deleting the suo file does nothing and trying to checkout the branch just has it create a new local branch instead, just re-clone and save yourself time.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue (VS 2022). My situation sounds very similar to [Patrick's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70498918/5460182), so I'll share how I fixed it in case it helps anyone:

In my case, the branch switch looked successful at first (in reality it hadn't completed), and  then I started receiving said exception immediately afterwards. According to the Git Changes toolbar, I was trying to add a file that existed in the branch I was coming from that wasn't present yet in the branch I was going to. (Note there were several files that existed in one branch but not the other. But for some reason, this particular one had tripped things up.)

All I had to do was this:

1. Take the file in question out of the directory
2. *From the shell window*, switch back to the first branch, then switch to the second branch again. After this, everything merged fine for me and Visual Studio stopped throwing that exception.

(For those that don't know how to do any of this, you can get to the command line from Tools -> Command Line. Then enter `git switch branch_name` where "branch_name" is the name of the branch you're switching *from*, then repeat the command with the name of the branch you're switching *to*. If that goes well, you can then merge the first branch into the second by typing `git merge branch_name` where "branch_name" is the branch you switched *from*.

Comment: "git switch branch_name" switches TO the branch, not from.  See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch

Comment: @Luminator That wasn't a typo. I can't explain the oddness. I did have this issue crop up one more time and I fixed it by the same means. Perhaps some internal state wasn't correct, and performing the two switch commands that way brought everything back in line?

Answer (score 1):

If you are having this problem you need to think high level.  I got this problem when I was trying to switch to a different git branch and it was really fussing and going back to the original git branch when it failed.   If you don't have a lot of changes in your local repo I have a simple solution for you.

Go to your repos directory and delete the folder for the project that is giving you this ...GitCheckout... problem. Obviously this solution will lose any changes in your local repo so only do this if you've just checked in. It may be that since you only get this message trying to switch to a different branch, you haven't made a lot of changes there yet. Nothing wrong with checking changes in for the branch you are stuck on and then trying what I suggest. Then clone that repository again to your local repo and go from there to the git branch you want.   To do that in VS 2019 pick the "Clone a Repository" and pick the high level project you want to clone.   There's nothing wrong with your central git repository, this message is just some syncing issue in Visual Studio between the git resource and your local repo that only 5 people who work for Microsoft really understand.

In my opinion the microsoft implementation of git can have only one branch in your repo at a time.  If you are having trouble changing branches for a given project, and there are no changes on your side to check in,there is nothing wrong with deleting that directory reference in your repos directory and requesting a fresh copy.   If that fresh copy isn't the branch you want, at that time you can request the branch you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your branch was renamed.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case: For me the solution was re-open the solution as administrator and make sure that you do not have pending files to protect if you are trying to move to another branch

[image: No error message anymore]

Answer (score 1):

You can delete index.lock file in your directory(C:/...(your project)/.git/index.lock), then add some changes(space on any row for example) and then push commit. It will work

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I tried to undo all my changes, (since my teammate already created the same files) and update branch by 'pull'. It should not have merge conflicts since I removed and undo all changes.

Finally what I did to solve this is by:

1. checkout/switch to another branch,
2. then delete the problematic branch in my local.
3. Pull latest for the 'another branch',
4. and then go to remotes/origin to check out the problematic branch again.

**update: I get to know why this is happening, after all is resolved I got the error on existing open tab mentioning file conflicts, so, the culprit will be, I create some new files, they are on open tab; and I delete those files, and perform branch pull. In the vs cache those files are exist and clashing with the latest commits. Long story short, try to close all existing tab if you are going to undo changes you did that will conflict with incoming changes.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because we have our appsettings.development.json files set to ignore uncommitted changes by running:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree appsettings.development.json
```

So when someone had changed the json file & pushed it in to master, when we did a pull we would get the same error message because our local has been told not to track the changes but master had been changed.

So the answer was to set it to no longer ignore changes by running:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree appsettings.development.json
```

Doing a pull should then no longer receive that message.

Answer (score 0):

An other reason can be that someone **renamed the branch on the server**.

In my case someone renamed the branch `Feature/abc` to `feature/abc` (capital letter change) and therefore I got a *Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Contracts.**PushForceRequiredException*** in Visual Studio.

(It's a different error than in the question, but when you search for it in Google then this StackOverflow topic is the first search result. So it could be useful for some people. Actually I saw the different exception name just after writing this answer.)

**How to solve:**

- Enter directory `.git` in the project directory
- Open file `config` in a text editor
- Search for the problematical branch name and adjust the origins branch name
- Save the file
- Try again in Visual Studio

The entries in the `config` file look like this:

```
[branch "Feature/abc"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/Feature/abc
```